# How do I get the value inside the dictionary if it's key is stored inside a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, dictionary

I need to get a value of the key that I've stored inside a variable. The value of the variable varies and the output pattern should vary according to this. Please check the code below I don't seem to get the output. I could get them only if I could pass the value for the key given. It would be nice if you point out any other errors in this programs since I'm very NEW to this. Thanks :)

```
self = {
       "1" : None,
       "0" : "",
       "2" : "abc",
       "3" : "def",
       "4" : "ghi",
       "5" : "jkl",
       "6" : "mno",
       "7" : "pqrs",
       "8" : "uvw",
       "9" : "wxyz"
}
def rec(rest_of_no, path):
        if not rest_of_no:
            combinations.add(path)
            return
        first, rest = rest_of_no[0], rest_of_no[1:]
        letters = self.get[int(first)] 

        for letter in letters:
            rec(rest_of_no, path)
            return combinations 

t = int(input())
for i in range(t):
    n = int(input())
    ar = list(map(int, input().split()))
    combinations = set()
    rec(ar, "")

    print (combinations)
```

This is the error that I get:

```
    Runtime Error:
Runtime ErrorTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/66ec1f75836d265709dd36b77f69f071.py", line 30, in <module>
    rec(ar, "")
  File "/home/66ec1f75836d265709dd36b77f69f071.py", line 19, in rec
    letters=self[int(first)] 
KeyError: 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things off with your code. First, why use `eval` at all?

```
letters = self.get(first)  
# will do just fine instead of
letters = self.get(eval('first'))
```

Second, the keys of your `self` dictionary (which is a really bad name for a random variable that is not the instance passed to a method) are strings. But `ar` contains integers which is why `first` is an `int` and `self.get(first)` returns `None`.

Moreover, as pointed out by AndrejKesely:

```
if not rec:
# should probably be 
if not rest_of_no:
```

And the recursive call with the same arguments will cause infinite recursion while `return rec` returns a function object which is probably not your intention. Lots of debugging still required ;)

Comment: There are other errors too, like `if not rec` when `rec` is function's name.

Comment: The use of the variable name `self` outside of class instances is a bit odd too.

Comment: @AndrejKesely True. But that doesn't cause the error (or any error for that matter) ;) Still added it.

Comment: @schwobaseggl and lastly, the program will go to infinite recursion, because it's called in `rec` with the same parameters `rec(rest_of_no, path)` ;)

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thing is, the OP asked about a particular error, not to debug their entire program ;) there is even more: `return rec` does most likely not do what the OP expects.